# dynamically reference a cell in a closed file

Tags: excel-formula

I have a series of closed files with filenames depicted the month and year, i.e. Activity_(Dec_2016).xlsm.  I am trying to get the value of cell K47, but the month varies. Here is my formula:

```
INDEX("'C:\...\[Activity_("&TEXT(A2,"MMM")&"_2016).xlsm]18'!K47",1,1,1)
```

Cell A2 = `Today()` with the format of MM/DD/YYYY
The result is a #VALUE error.  When I hard code in the date, i.e. "Dec_2016", in place of the TEXT function it returns the correct value.  Can this be done with excel (not vba)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A few thoughts: the fact that the file is closed sounds like a distracting element to your real question here, but just to confirm, does it start working when the file in question is open?  If not, I'd take "closed file" out of the question title.  Second, why use INDEX?  Can you not use `='C:\...\[Activity_Jan_2016.xlsm]18'!$K$47'`?

Comment: The target files is closed, i.e., it is not open while being referenced.  I selected INDEX because my research let me to believe that was the best function for referencing a closed file.  The "Jan_2016" could be "Nov_2014", so that part of the file name needs to be variable not hard coded, but the rest of the file name and path is static.

Comment: I hard-coded the month because I was trying to use code that was known to work without the `INDEX` function (thereby eliminating an extra function and the closed file issue).  Then way focus can shift exclusively to the dynamically generated month.

Comment: The strange thing is hard-coding the month actually works; the Text function works, but the two together do not work.